# VueJs Laravel pagination

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a problem with installing laravel-vue-pagination.
I'm building SPA Crud app for some testing and it's not going very well with the finish.
I have installed successfully pagination on the backend part but the frontend is pretty messy.
It's always giving errors like:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "laravelData" is not defined on the
> instance but referenced during render.  found in
>
> --->  at resources/js/components/CustomerList.vue
>  at resources/js/App.vue

and this is how App.vue looks like:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">

    <div class="container">
      <MyForm :form="form" @onFormSubmit="onFormSubmit" />
      <Loader v-if="loader" />
      <CustomerList
        :customers="customers"
        @onDelete="onDelete"
        @onEdit="onEdit"
      />

    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import MyForm from "./components/MyForm";
import CustomerList from "./components/CustomerList";
import Loader from "./components/Loader";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    MyForm,
    CustomerList,
    Loader
  },
  data() {
    return {
      url: "http://localhost:8000/api/leads",
      leads: [],
      laravelData: {},
      form: { name: "", lastname: "", phoneNumber: "", birthday: "", isEdit: false },
      loader: false
    };
  },
  mounted() {
        // Fetch initial results
        this.getCustomers();
    },
  methods: {
    
    getCustomers(page) {
      this.loader = true;
      if (typeof page === 'undefined') {
          page = 1;
      }
      axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/leads?page=' + page).then(data => {
        this.laravelData = data.data; 
        this.loader = false;
      });
    },
    
    deleteCustomer(id) {
      this.loader = true;

      axios
        .delete(`${this.url}/${id}`)
        .then(() => {
          this.getCustomers();
        })
        .catch(e => {
          alert(e);
        });
    },
    createCustomer(data) {
      this.loader = true;

      axios
        .post(this.url, {
          name: data.name,
          lastname: data.lastname,
          phoneNumber: data.phoneNumber,
          birthday: data.birthday
        })
        .then(() => {
          this.getCustomers();
        })
        .catch(e => {
          alert(e);
        });
    },
    editCustomer(data) {
      this.loader = true;

      axios
        .put(`${this.url}/${data.id}`, {
          name: data.name,
          lastname: data.lastname,
          phoneNumber: data.phoneNumber,
          birthday: data.birthday
        })
        .then(() => {
          this.getCustomers();
        })
        .catch(e => {
          alert(e);
        });
    },
    onDelete(id) {
      // window.console.log("app delete " + id);

      this.deleteCustomer(id);
    },
    onEdit(data) {
      // window.console.log("app edit ", data);

      this.form = data;
      this.form.isEdit = true;
    },
    onFormSubmit(data) {
      // window.console.log("app onFormSubmit", data);

      if (data.isEdit) {
        // call edit customer
        this.editCustomer(data);
      } else {
        // call create customer
        this.createCustomer(data);
      }
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.getCustomers();
  }
};
</script>
```

The problem is clearly because laravelData is not getting the data that is needed, but why?
This is how json response looks like:

```
{
    "current_page": 1,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Rade",
            "lastname": "Ilijev",
            "birthday": "1998-11-21",
            "phoneNumber": 612169456,
            "created_at": "2020-07-13T10:52:58.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-07-13T18:25:49.000000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 13,
            "name": "asdasd",
            "lastname": "kajsdhaksd",
            "birthday": "1111-11-11",
            "phoneNumber": 29292929,
            "created_at": "2020-07-13T19:04:59.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2020-07-13T19:04:59.000000Z"
        }
    ],
    "first_page_url": "http://localhost:8000/api/leads?page=1",
    "from": 1,
    "last_page": 1,
    "last_page_url": "http://localhost:8000/api/leads?page=1",
    "next_page_url": null,
    "path": "http://localhost:8000/api/leads",
    "per_page": 19,
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "to": 5,
    "total": 5
}
```

This is error that happens in CusomerList.vue

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data'
> of undefined"
>
> found in
>
> --->  at resources/js/components/CustomerList.vue
>  at resources/js/App.vue

And this is how CustomerList.vue looks like:

```
<template>
<div id="rade-table">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-dark">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>PhoneNumber</th>
            <th>Birthday</th>
            <th style="width: 148px;">Action</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
          <Customer
            v-for="customer in laravelData.data"
            :key="customer.id"
            :customer="customer"
            @onDelete="onDelete"
            @onEdit="onEdit"
          />
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <pagination
        :data="laravelData" @pagination-change-page="getResults"
      ></pagination>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
import Customer from "./Customer";
export default {
  name: "CustomerList",
  components: {
    Customer
  },
  props: {
    customers: {
      type: Array
    }
  },
  
  methods: {

    onDelete(id) {
      // window.console.log("customer list delete " + id);
      this.$emit("onDelete", id);
    },
    onEdit(data) {
      // window.console.log("customer list edit " + data);
      this.$emit("onEdit", data);
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

Here is the file how I'm rending Customer data as Customer.vue file

```
<template>
  <tr>
    <td>{{ customer.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ customer.name }} {{ customer.lastname }}</td>
    <td>{{ customer.phoneNumber }}</td>
    <td>{{ customer.birthday }}</td>
    <td>
      <button class="btn rade-button-rounded-edit" @click="onEdit"><i class='far fa-edit'></i></button>
      <button class="btn rade-button-rounded-delete" @click="onDelete"><i class='far fa-trash-alt'></i></button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Customer",
  props: {
    customer: {
      type: Object
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onDelete() {
      // window.console.log("customer delete " + this.customer.id);
      this.$emit("onDelete", this.customer.id);
    },
    onEdit() {
      // window.console.log("customer edit " + this.customer.id);
      this.$emit("onEdit", this.customer);
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

This is a app.js:

```
require('./bootstrap');
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.component('pagination', require('laravel-vue-pagination'));

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

maybe here is the problem?

Ofc here is the error like

> Property or method "customers" is not defined on the instance but
> referenced during render

App is actually working like that, but I would like to fix this as well.
Here is the git for cleaner look https://github.com/rade98/laravel

Comment: Your `CustomerList` component doesn't have a prop/data called `laravelData`, it has a `prop` called `customers`. Try to replace `laravelData` with `customers` in your CustomerList

Comment: Clearly that's solution for laravelData. But still problem like Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined"

Comment: Isn't that related? `laravelData` is undefined but you want to read `laravelData.data` in `v-for="customer in laravelData.data"`

Comment: It is, but when I changed first that you said, I don't have error for laravelData

Comment: In your `App.vue`: `:customers="customers"` Your App doesn't have `customers` data, it seems to be `laravelData`.

Comment: It's still the same. Can you take a look at git? There must be some connection with that